# Ruby on Rails: rosource RESOURCE_NAME dosent generate index route/action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im currently trying to use the resource but one problem im having , that when i do the following

```
resource :orders
```

the route **/orders** dosent route to **OrdersController#index** rather it points to the **show** action of the controller, how can i fix this issue ?

[image: this is the routes that are generated]

becuase of this problem im having to do this which i feel is kinda hack and not good

```rb
  get '/orders', to: 'orders#index'
  get '/orders/:id', to: 'orders#show'
```

this is my `routes.rb` file

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/carts', to: 'carts#index'

  get '/payments', to: 'payments#index'
  post '/payments', to: 'payments#add_credits'

  get '/orders', to: 'orders#index'
  get '/orders/:id', to: 'orders#show'

  resources :users do
    resource :orders, only: %i[show create index]
    resource :carts, only: %i[create destroy], path: 'cart', as: 'cart'
  end

  resource :sessions, only: [] do
    post 'login', action: :create
    post 'logout', action: :destroy
    get 'login', action: :new
  end
  resources :products
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file, the whole file.

Comment: @RockwellRice i added that,

Comment: @RockwellRice my bad sorry, it alredy generated that but i didint see that

Comment: Well, you put the order resource inside `Users` so if you are looking to get  just an `/orders` URL that won't work.  It is hard to tell what you are trying to do here.  Do you want just the basic orders URLS not inside `Users`?  if so add the resource outside of `Users`  Just and FYI, you can have both the ful resource outside of USers and then those restricted routes inside Users, but I'm not sure what the goal is here so it is up to you to decide that.

Comment: @RockwellRice you can conside posting this as the answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use

```
resource :orders
```

use

```
resources :orders
```

You would only use `resource` when the item `orders` is a single entity in your application... which is to say you're using the plural to refer to that one item.

Answer (score 1):

Move the resource for orders outside of the `Users` routes.

Just and FYI, you can have both the full resource outside of Users and then those restricted routes inside Users, but I'm not sure what the goal is here so it is up to you to decide that.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/carts', to: 'carts#index'

  get '/payments', to: 'payments#index'
  post '/payments', to: 'payments#add_credits'

  resources :orders

  resources :users do
    resource :orders, only: %i[show create index] <-- not sure if this remains here
    resource :carts, only: %i[create destroy], path: 'cart', as: 'cart'
  end
...
```